# how to check only city name when user enter full address and i stored city in my database

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps-api-3

Hi i have one table where i store full address and in one field and only city name in other field.
table fields (id, address, city, hotel_name)

if user search based on street as well, but if there is a result for that street, it should appear first then should show the remining result for the city e.g user search for Russel Street New York then website show the result for the " Russel street first" and then show the result for New York or near that street.

i have currently pass full address in google places api and they return me city name so i filter that city record in city field, but some case google api not return any city name if search string have city name. so have any other way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally put an IF in the ORDER BY if this behaviour is required:

```
 SELECT street, city FROM (
    SELECT 'street 1' street, 'city 1' city
        UNION ALL
    SELECT 'street 2' street, 'city 2' city
        UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL street, 'city 1' city
        UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL street, 'city 2' city
) AS A
ORDER BY city, IF(street IS NULL, 1, 0);
```

[image]

Does this solve your issue?

(After comment apparently not, how about this:)

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cityTable SELECT 'city1' cityCol UNION ALL SELECT 'city2' UNION ALL SELECT 'city3';

SET @Search = 'street1 city1';

SELECT @Search, cityCol FROM cityTable WHERE @Search LIKE CONCAT('%', cityCol, '%');
```

If not please post some sample data and an example of the problem in your question.

Regards,

James

Comment: thanks dear, but user enter full address when they search, like i specify above, so how i can identify city from it and compare it with city field. as google api not give me city name every time with different combination of search strings.

Comment: Thanks, i tried your given solutions, and it's work for me.

Comment: Great, pleased to have helped